# Shape of button in android changes undesirably when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to create a customized button of a particular shape to toggle its text and button background colors. But when i do this , the shape of the button changes when i click it.
This is my activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#5e7974"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Buttons"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="changecolorbutton" />
```

The file in my drawable folder named mybutton.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="7dip" />
        <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#5e7974" android:endColor="#5e7974"  />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
        <solid android:color="#58857e"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="7dip" />
        <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

My MainActivity.java looks like this

```
Button button;
public void changecolorbutton(View v)
{
    Button bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5e7974"));
    //bt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshape); -> i tried to change shape again but doesnt work
}
```

When I run the code the colors of the button change as i want it to, but the shape of the button becomes its default after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I can not add comment. So I post as answer.

Why is *bt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshape);* ?

Why not *bt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybutton);*?

My guess is the button skips shapes because you override the background

```
bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5e7974"));
```